# HTML <Details> tag should closes when other details tag open up in ionic for function TypeScript

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

This what I have in the typescript file. I'm doing this ionic.

```js
thisindex_1(elm){
  var nodes = elm.parentNode.childNodes, node;
  var i = 0, count = i;
  while( (node=nodes.item(i++)) && node!=elm )
    if( node.nodeType==1 ) count++;
  return count;
}

closeAll(index){
  var len = document.getElementsByTagName("details").length;

  for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
    if(i != index){
      document.getElementsByTagName("details")[i].removeAttribute("open");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<details (click) = closeAll(thisindex_1(this))>
  <summary>1</summary>Demo 1
</details>

<details (click) = closeAll(thisindex_1(this))>
  <summary>2</summary>Demo 2
</details>

<details (click) = closeAll(thisindex_1(this))>
  <summary>3</summary>Demo 3
</details>
```

Building application using ionic (html, angular) for the front-end and typescript.

HTML  tag should closes when other details tag open up in ionic for function TypeScript.

"Giving this error Runtime Error. Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined."

It keeps gives this error.

Comment: Why are you using native javascript when you are using the Angular. Create the stackblitz demo for the same.

Comment: you forget all the " when define click, e.g.  <details (click)="closeAll(thisindex_1(this))">. Anyway, "this" has no value in the .html